# Debugging stop after executing JSONArray JSONObject , cannot execute for loop?

Tags: android, arrays, json, for-loop, debugging

I am new in calling `api` , i have just tried a simple example of `api` call using `http` and trying to put it in `ListView` , but it is showing `NULLPointerExecption` , i debug the code and debugging stops after it reaches `JSONArray` object creation? why so i really do not know about that, I also tried to set Shinking option true/false in `gradle` file but nothing is happening...

i have included my whole project in one `mainactivity` only.  here is the code...

```
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);

                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);

                    singleParsed = "\n" + "\n" + "NAME : " + jo.get("name") + "\n" +
                            "PASSWORD : " + jo.get("password") + "\n" +
                            "CONTACT : " + jo.get("contact") + "\n" +
                            "COUNTRY : " + jo.get("country") + "\n";

                    dataParsed = dataParsed + singleParsed + "\n";
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                return ParseMoviesJsonString(dataParsed);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }




        private ArrayList<User> ParseMoviesJsonString(String dataParsed) throws JSONException {

            final String json_name = "name";
            final String json_password = "password";
            final String json_contact = "contact";
            final String json_country = "country";

            ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<>();

            JSONObject MovieJson = new JSONObject(dataParsed);//MovieJson got the data and then skipps the followinglines and directly go to onPostExecute
            JSONArray MovieArray = MovieJson.getJSONArray(dataParsed);

            for (int i = 0; i < MovieArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject result_movie = MovieArray.getJSONObject(i);
                User movie = new User();
                movie.setU_name(result_movie.getString(json_name));
                movie.setU_password(result_movie.getString(json_password));
                movie.setU_contact(result_movie.getString(json_contact));
                movie.setU_country(result_movie.getString(json_country));

                list.add(movie);
            }
            return list;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<User> list) {// list : null
            super.onPostExecute(list);

            adapter.updateList(list);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are posting entire Activity code? Just post related code and logcat.

Comment: @Yash Can you post your JASON response and Logcat error

Comment: Access denied finding property "hwservicemanager.ready"

Comment: DisplayBase::BuildLayerStackStats: LayerStack layer_count: 4, app_layer_count: 3, gpu_target_index: 3, display type: 0

Comment: logcat is showing this only

Comment: and i cannot put image over here because i donot have that much reputation

Comment: `adapter` is `NULL` and `ArrayList<User> list` is `NULL` ...how is this supposed to work?

Comment: yes adapter is null beacuse my arraylist is null, and my arraylist is null because its not executing foor loop

Comment: i have edited my code

Comment: i have commented from the line it skipps debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your asynctask as per given below

```
   @Override
    protected ArrayList<User> doInBackground(String[] params) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1422e4");

            HttpURLConnection hc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = hc.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            while (line != null) {
                line = br.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }

        /*      JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);

          for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);

                singleParsed = "\n" + "\n" + "NAME : " + jo.get("name") + "\n" +
                        "PASSWORD : " + jo.get("password") + "\n" +
                        "CONTACT : " + jo.get("contact") + "\n" +
                        "COUNTRY : " + jo.get("country") + "\n";

                dataParsed = dataParsed + singleParsed + "\n";
            }*/

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            return ParseMoviesJsonString(data);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    private ArrayList<User> ParseMoviesJsonString(String dataParsed) throws JSONException {

        final String json_name = "name";
        final String json_password = "password";
        final String json_contact = "contact";
        final String json_country = "country";

        ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<>();

        JSONArray MovieArray = new JSONArray(dataParsed);

        for (int i = 0; i < MovieArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject result_movie = MovieArray.getJSONObject(i);
            User movie = new User();
            movie.setU_name(result_movie.getString(json_name));
            movie.setU_password(result_movie.getString(json_password));
            movie.setU_contact(result_movie.getString(json_contact));
            movie.setU_country(result_movie.getString(json_country));

            list.add(movie);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

as per above solution you have to comment the code in doinbackground and also make some changes as in parsing. you can also try using GSON library and that is better way .

Comment: You have to just copy paste my whole code in your asynctask